# can someone help to correct a reversal for a list within lists?

Tags: python, list, reverse

I am trying to reverse the following:

```
z = list(reversed(i) for i in zip(['FRED', 'CORWILL'], ['WILFRED', 'CORWILL'], ['RAPHAEL', 'CORWILL'], ['ALFRED', 'CORWILL'], ['BARNEY', 'TORNBULL'], ['BETTY', 'TORNBULL'], ['BJON', 'TORNBULL']))

print(z)
```

So basically, I need ['FRED', 'CORWILL'] to become ['CORWILL','FRED] and the same for all the other lists.

Can someone please help to amend the above code, instead of writing entirely new code to achieve the desired output?

THanks

Comment: Don't use `zip()`.

Comment: How do you find yourself having that many independent lists?  Seems odd that they wouldn't actually be inside one larger list.

Comment: Why don't you just write `z = thedatathewayyouactuallywantit`? It's btw not clear how you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overcomplicated the problem, the reverse function you use already solved it for you!

```
print(list(reversed(["FRED", 'CORWILL'])))
```

For the multiple case, you just need to repeat the process for each of the lists of names.

```
print(list(list(reversed(names)) for names in [['FRED', 'CORWILL'], ['JOHN', 'MARIA']]))
```

Notice that I used `list(reversed(i))` and not `reversed(i)`, since reversed returns a generator, and not an actual list which we can see when printed. The following would be the output as you were doing it:

> [<list_reverseiterator object at 0x0000024119326EB0>,
> <list_reverseiterator object at 0x0000024119326EE0>]

Comment: Added it! -----

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my input is [['FRED', 'CORWILL'], ['WILFRED', 'CORWILL'], ['RAPHAEL', 'CORWILL'], ['ALFRED', 'CORWILL'], ['BARNEY', 'TORNBULL'], ['BETTY', 'TORNBULL'], ['BJON', 'TORNBULL']] - does that mean I need 7 of list(list(list(....))))))) ?

Comment: I believe your code works for [['FRED', 'CORWILL'], ['JOHN', 'MARIA']], but how about if we have [['FRED', 'CORWILL'], ['WILFRED', 'CORWILL'], ['RAPHAEL', 'CORWILL']] - does this mean I need list(list(list(...)))?

Comment: that is why I added the for loop, because I need reversed to be applied to each of the smaller lists (list of two items) that is within the bigger list.

Comment: the second code block works for +1 lists!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `zip`, `reversed`, `list`...

```
initial = [
    ['FRED', 'CORWILL'],
    ['WILFRED', 'CORWILL'],
    ['RAPHAEL', 'CORWILL'],
    ['ALFRED', 'CORWILL'],
    ['BARNEY', 'TORNBULL'],
    ['BETTY', 'TORNBULL'],
    ['BJON', 'TORNBULL']
]
```

You could do this:

```
swapped = [[b, a] for [a, b]  in initial]
```

Or even this:

```
swapped = [sublist[::-1] for sublist  in initial]
```